# Gradle : how to translate "type" and "scope" from Maven dependency?

Tags: java, gradle

my Java project has a dependency in Maven like this :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but when I write this in gradle, it does not recognize and I found no jar :

```
implementation 'com.dependency:some-artifact'
```

I wonder the reason is that I have to specify `type` and `scope` also, but I don't know what is the gradle equivalent to these two ?

Comment: Is this jar something you have control over? Normally test jars should not go in a repository

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen in fact I want to use the Maven dependency which is declared as such in another project in my Gradle project, but it failed to fetch the correct jar. I'm sure the Maven dependency declaration is 100% correct

Comment: What's the version of your dependency? Is it mentioned in `<dependencyManagement>`?

Answer (score 2):

The Gradle equivalent of `scope` is called *configuration*. The *configuration* that is equivalent to Maven's `test` `scope` is `testImplementation`.

There is no equivalent to Maven's `type` configuration in Gradle. However, there're `classifier` and `extension`. The `classifier` for `test-jar` is `tests` (according to the [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html)).

Putting it all together, and for demonstration purposes assuming the version of the dependency is `1.0.0`, you should declare the dependency like this:

```
testImplementation 'com.dependency:some-artifact:1.0.0:tests'
```

Further reading:

- [Dependency management in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency-types)
- [Declaring dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html)
- [DependencyHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html)